# Automatically capture the video with iPHone OS 3.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I have just view the iPhone application Touch Cam (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touch-cam-video-recording/id337848815?mt=8) which provides the capturing video automatically.

There is no api provided for this in iPHone OS 3.x.

Is there any hidden API (Undocumented ) is available for this. or how can we start the capturing of video automatically.

Look forward for positive response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UIImagePickerController to allow the user to capture video and provide custom overlays if you don't want the standard view.  This has been available since iOS 3.1.